# Getting length of colormap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to get length of matplotlib colormap?

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'])
```

something like cmap.len()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of colors is in member `colors`:

```
len(cmap.colors)
```

You can use `cmap.N` too.

Answer (score 2):

the proper way to get length is to use 
`cmap.N`:

```
>>> cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c'])
>>> cmap.N
```

output

```
4
```